# Slack上で特定のアカウントのコメントのみの一斉削除

Tags: python, slack

SlackでSlackbotで決まった時間を通知したり、Incoming Webhooksを使ってPythonを実行した際の通知をSlackに飛ばしています。
ですが、過去の通知が溜まってきており無料プランの10000件を圧迫しそうです。
チャンネルごとではなく特定のアカウント（この場合SlackbotやIncoming Webhooks）の投稿のみ一斉削除する方法はあるでしょうか？（検索してもうまく見つけられませんでした。）

Python等外部の言語を使う方法でも構いません。

**追記**

```
Failed to delete (cant_delete_message)->
{'bot_id': 'B01',
'text': 'hoge',
'ts': 'fuga',
'type': 'message',
'user': 'USLACKBOT'}

0 message(s) cleaned.
```

のようなメッセージがでて消去できないです…

Answer (score 3):

おすすめの手段としては、 [slack-cleaner](https://github.com/kfei/slack-cleaner) というpython製のアプリケーションがあるので、こちらを使うことです。

インストール後に `slack-cleaner --token <SlackのTOKEN> --message --channel <チャンネル名> --user <BOTのアカウント名>` のように利用します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'とのエラーが出てしまいます。実行環境はPython3だと思われます。対処方法はご存知でしょうか。

Comment: python3で動かすことが出来ないようです。python2を利用するか、詳しくは調べていないのですが、python3に対応した別の方のフォーク( https://github.com/sgratzl/slack-cleaner ) があるようなので、そちらだと利用できるかもしれません。

Comment: フォークを使ったらかなりいいところまで行きました。ありがとうございます。ですが、あと一息のところでうまくいきません。ご助言等ありましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `あと一息のところでうまくいきません` とは、具体的にどのような問題が発生したのでしょうか。

Comment: すいません。フォークをpipでインストールして教えていただいたとおりにやったところ上に追記のとおりfail to deleteになりました。